# Div height of parent

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some problems with setting height of a child div. I've got 2 divs , one of them with picture and the other with text.

Both of them are in parent div.

You can check it here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/JgkgB/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content-news">
    <div class="news_content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore t dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
    </div><!--news_content-->

    <div class="post_image">
    <img src="http://ec.l.thumbs.canstockphoto.com/canstock13365568.jpg" />
    </div><!--post image-->

</div><!--content news-->
```

**CSS:**

```
.content-news {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.post_image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 9px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    max-width: 140px;
    width: 100%;

}

.news_content {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 527px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I already tried to use JavaScript or jQuery but it doesn't help me.

All I need is to make text-div same height as the picture-div.

I used search to find some questions that may help me, but it didn't.

Comment: Please post your code in your question. Thanks!

Comment: @j08691 It kind of seems like SO moderators go back and forth on this; sometimes a working example is best, sometimes they prefer code to be posted. Why have both, with the potential for a typo in either one?

Comment: @Katana314 - Because third-party sites, like jsFiddle.net, could go away one day, be blocked by your employer, or vanish for a variety of reasons, rendering questions without code meaningless. Sites like jsFiddle.net should supplement the question, not be the sole source for the code.

Comment: @j08691 To be fair its not like this question hasn't been asked before. But I know what you mean, I would say the code should be in the question and then a live version (JSFiddle) is a bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
position: relative;
```

to your `.content-news`

and

```
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
```

to your `.news_content` and that should work. http://fiddle.jshell.net/JgkgB/3/

Comment: Thank you veeery much. You are my hero <3

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :) Just a little information: You can accept Answers below the arrows to vote this answer. It'd help @Ed T. and stackoverflow if you would accept his answer if it helped you! :) (And you also gain rep. for it :P )

Answer (score 1):

add this

```
.content-news {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery:

```
$(".news_content").css({'height':($(".post_image").height()+'px')});
```

That should work for setting the same height on the text DIV.

Answer (score 1):

Heights in percentage won't work if you use floats. Try to use `display: table-cell;`

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/skeurentjes/JgkgB/13/

Answer (score 0):

One way is to simply set the height of both elements in the CSS like so :

```
height:enter-height;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JgkgB/

Comment: It is well known that you can't set element heights to 100% :P